# How to perfectly display full-screen google maps on both iPad and iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, ipad, google-maps

What is the best way to show a full-screen google map on both iPad and iPhone and even when the orientation changed as well.

Edit: I'm implementing mobile application in jQuery mobile. not iOS application. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically Google Mps API renders the map into an `div`(some cases in an `iframe`). Anyway you should specify an div to be your *Map Canvas*. if you change size of the `div`, then size of the map will change.
So if you define `width` and `height` of the canvas to `100%`, it will always show the map covering whole screen.

```
#mapCanvas{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

Comment: but I think I still have to set the size of outer div anyway?

Comment: your outer div should be 100% by 100% too. In most basic setup you need to set width and height of `html`, `body`, `.wrapperDiv`, `.mapcanvas` to `100%`. if any parent element has a fixed size then it will break.

Answer (score -2):

You need to create what is called as universal app if your intention is to develop a single app for ipad and iphone. 
Check this link out on some tricks on creating such an app

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW6

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm doing Mobile Application. not native application.